# Graphql client and server in the same machine, network layer performance

Tags: graphql

If both are running on the same machine, is there a way to make a more direct call (fast) instead of using the network layer (slow) wen is not needed?

Comment: I would imagine that depends a lot on what the client is, what the server is, and what you think "a more direct call" is. GraphQL is just a specification. While there are certain implementations and conventions, in the end, you can create whatever sort of client and server you want. So, if you want to come up with something that communicates over some form of IPC, you are welcome to... but you may have to do more of that implementation work yourself.

Comment: is there a IPC implementation of the network layer for graphql server-client? would be nice to be flexible if its a browser doing the server call (do normal http) or if its server-side rendering so IPC would be used instead